# Blob detection using Python 2.7 Opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, blob, contour

I have a binary image  which has 5 contours (5 white filled circles and background of the image is black).
I want to do the blob analysis within my image.
I want to discriminate the color, area, centroid etc of the circles using Python 2.7 and opencv

Please show me the code and example.

Comment: Take your *give me teh coodz* attitude somewhere else.  It isn't welcome here.

Comment: This may help you: https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/